# Options for automatically finding and applying C# 6 features

Tags: c#

What tooling exists, if any, to detect cases where an existing C# code base could leverage C# 6 features. Specifically, I want to find cases where I could use expression bodied functions and properties, and the null-conditional operator. Bonus if the tool can automatically make the changes on my behalf.

I'd greatly prefer if the tool was either free or part of VS2015 Ultimate (I can't find anything built in).